# Rendering a PDF from Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am wondering if anyone has a suggestion on the best practice for rendering a pdf from an LWC.  I have a visualforce page that does the rendering now, I pass some values from another visualforce page to render the PDF.  The first Visualforce page is getting replaced with an LWC but now I'm unsure of how to handle producing a PDF from that lightning web component.  Thanks!!!

Comment: this doesn't look like LWC and is over 2 years old.  Was hoping for something more recent and for LWC.  thanks!

Comment: I don't think anything has really changed since that answer (would love to be wrong). Either iframe a VF page (which can render as a pdf and begs the question of whether to just stick with VF period) or use some external js library that can render PDFs and works nicely with LWC. I haven't done that myself so can't provide any concrete options although the answer linked suggests PDF.js.

Comment: I just use the lwc viewer at https://github.com/annyhe/pdfViewer with good result. Doesn't require visualforce.